# How to integrate the API and UI framework in Selenium using JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, integration, rest-assured

API - RestAssured API
UI - Selenium UI
Integration needed from API to UI
using Selenium and Maven dependencies in JAVA

How to call the UI framework from API ?

Comment: RestAssured and Selenium are jus libs, you can treat them as normal java libs. And please add specific question, people cannot help you if they don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Can you please share more details about API and UI framework and where you stuck?

Comment: This is my scenario - 1)I have an API to test using Rest Assured . 2) I have Selenium UI to test the UI for the record created from API in step 1 .3) How to achieve this scenario using cucumber feature file and java calls ?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments section here is my understanding of your requirement :

You want to use rest assured to call an API and create data and then verify the same whether it is visible or present on UI using selenium scripts.

Now, I don't know the exact functionality you want to test but here are my 2 cents.

First of all, what you are trying to achieve from your test is that whether the front and code and the back end code honour the contract between each other or not or in other words whether they are integrated correctly or not.

For example: From the browser, you try to create the record, for which browser may be making API calls then display the same data, one of the ways the test case can fail is that if there is any mismatch in the response objects data type and the data type your front end code is expecting.

Other failure points are on the API level - maybe service is down or the code logic itself is wrong, and UI level - front end code is itself not able to load the record because of UI code logic issue or browser-specific issue.

Now, if we follow your approach, then in cucumber I will write my steps like this :

> GivenICallCreateRecordAPICall
>
> WhenICheckTheDataFromUI
>
> ThenItShouldMatchCorrectly

Now, the first step will implement the rest assured call to create the record in the same environment and saving data to be verified with UI.
Second, Call UI using selenium, extract and save the data to be verified,
And Last, assert all the data to verify and throw errors if otherwise.

But, this approach is wrong.
All layers of test should ideally be independent as this will cause flakiness.

### The objective here is to check whether the integration is correct or not, so write a contract test Or, in your API test cases verify the response schema and data type.

Still, if you want to know more detail on how to implement then, please let me know I will provide the implementation detail.